# How can i achieve this in LINQ-Queries?

Tags: c#, linq

```
List<double> Values = new List<double>();
foreach (var item in Level.Items)
{
    Values.Add(item.Keys);
}
```

I'm new for LINQ-Queries, So can anyone help how to write the above codes in LINQ-Queries.

Comment: What is the type of `Keys` and  `Items` ?

Comment: `item.Keys` type is `double` and `Level.Items` is `List<CustomItems>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<double> Values = new List<double>(Level.Items.Select(item => item.Keys));
```

Or

```
List<double> Values = Level.Items.Select(item => item.Keys).ToList();
```

In case you have to add items into *existing* list:

```
List<double> Values = new List<double>();

...

Values.AddRange(Level.Items.Select(item => item.Keys));
```

Comment: Good note with the much-beloved `AddRange` function :) +1

Comment: Just to add to your answer: OP states "LINQ Queries", which to me says "`from x in y select z`". You could also add the option for `var values = new List<double>((from item in Level.Items select item.Keys).ToList());`

Comment: @GeoffJames `.Select` is a linq query. `.Concat` is also. You need to know that there is `Method Syntax` and `Query-Syntax`, both use Linq Extension Methods.

Comment: @user3185569 From what I understand `.Select()` is just an extension method of the query - so yes, essentially the two are synonymous; I just thought it might be worth adding to the answer :)

Comment: @GeoffJames Linq is just a set of extension methods. `IEnumerable.Select` is a linq query. Query-Syntax (`From x in ...`) is a syntactic sugar to call the extension methods (or whatever pattern that matches the types used)

Comment: @user3185569 True. Good stuff to know. Can't edit my previous comment now, but I just realised that the `.ToList()` call would be redundant as the `List<T>` ctor takes `IEnumerable<T>`, which is what the query returns - whoops

Answer (score 3):

Use `Select`:

```
List<double> values = Level.Items.Select(item => item.Keys).ToList();
```

If `Keys` is a collection by its own then use `SelectMany`:

```
List<double> values = Level.Items.SelectMany(item => item.Keys).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
List<double> Values = Level.Items.Select(a => a.Keys).ToList();
```